# Building a server API with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I know ASP.NET Web API is the big thing now, but isn't it mainly for client consumed services (browser apps, mobile apps etc.)? I need to develop a server side API that is called by other servers in my app to perform operations, not retrieve models of data, but RPC calls, for example, UpdateCache(), CalculateAtomicExplosion(), SendNotification(), FindTheRabbit(). I used to do these things with WCF, but I see it's slowly becomes replaced by Web API, but is Web API designed for that task? Will I be able to bind a remote service and call it with a proxy class like I used to with WCF / asmx? Communicate with CLR objects? etc..

What's the best practice on completing this task with current technologies?

Thanks!

Comment: Web API is absolutely capable for this. You can use it for RPC calls too.

Comment: I know but is it designed for that? Is it the best solution for what I need to do? @PeterPorfy

Comment: I think you should choose WCF now if you need a different protocol binding than http. Web API also contains client components so you can use it from the other server. It is designed for http communication from the ground up so it is a much straightforward technology than wcf.  if you not intend to use other communication channel then I would use this.

Comment: You could always make use of Apache Thrift.